# Is it possible to use exisiting PWA in wechat mini program?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, progressive-web-apps, wechat, wechat-miniprogram

I need to implement a wechat mini-program which is expected to be nearly exact replica of an already deployed PWA. Is there a way I can use same codebase in wechat mini-program Or implement some kind of a bridge to achieve same.
PS: PWA was implemented using Ionic/Angular.

Comment: Perhaps is the only answer we could give you without seeing the code.

Comment: Looking for same do let me know if any solution found

Comment: @Mathias code is not required please read question again

Comment: Apologies, but I really dont understand, code of what? do I need to share the code of entire PWA? 
My question is to just know if its possible and is it best practice to put existing PWA in a WeChat mini-program.

Comment: Are you asking if it is possible to do something with some code that you wrote? If so, it's impossible to answer such a question without seeing that code.

Comment: @Mathias, [link](https://github.com/ionicthemes/ionic4-starter-app) this is the code I am looking to integrate in wechat mini-program.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in theory you simply add the WeChat JS SDK to your current application, then use the APIs provided to you to do what you require. You'll need a registered WeChat account so that you can get your tokens and secrets, otherwise you won't be able to call their API. If your account is an international rather than a mainland China account then you may have limitation on certain API, such as the WeChat store API (from what I remember.)

Go take a look here:
https://developers.weixin.qq.com/doc/offiaccount/en/OA_Web_Apps/

And possibly here:
https://open.weixin.qq.com/?lang=en

Comment: Thank you SumYungGuy for your response, But I am unable to imagine how can I do it as wechat uses their own convensions for html and css so can you share some documentaion links of same or a link to prototype would be great.
Also one of your shared link lands to 404 page.

Comment: Apologies for not responding sooner, and not answering your question correctly. 

You can develop WeChat mini-programs using other third-party systems, which will allow you to write the code in React or Vue, so you don't necessarily need WeChats proprietary languages. However, I don't think there is support for Angular, but you won't necessarily be starting from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

IINM, the technologies are similar, but possible issues are:

1. They only have an SDK for proprietary OSes from Microsoft and Apple, so if you use something like Linux, you're out of luck,
2. Their architecture seems to dictate two threads, one for the UI and one for JS, and this is not typical for web apps, so I'd imagine some re-work required to port.

ref: https://developers.weixin.qq.com/miniprogram/en/dev/framework/quickstart/#Differences-Between-Mini-Program-Development-and-Web-Development

Answer (score 0):

You need to use kbone, this has been released to answer that need.

https://github.com/Tencent/kbone

Comment: For thi [issue](https://github.com/Tencent/kbone/issues/109#issuecomment-868327182),kbone is not suit with angular.